# How to keep the node server running?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Locally, when my code is putting some data in mongodb through mongoose, if something is wrong, `(err)`, the error is displayed on the command prompt window used to start the server. And the node server is stopped. Is this what is know as  `synchronous`? My code :

```
User.findOne({id:myid}, function(err, user){
        if(err) return done(err);
        if(user) return done(null, user);
        else{
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.name = myname;
            newUser.id = myid

            newUser.save(function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                return done(null, newUser);
            });             
        }
    });
```

With the above code, if there is a duplicate entry i get the error `11000` from mongoose and the server is stopped. Do I need to edit wherever it says `return err`? What do I need to keep the server running with a message sent to the client (Angular) and not logged in the console that crashes the server. I'm fairly new to `MEAN` and still learning. The above code works perfect if the id is not duplicate. [I have the `id` field as `unique`]

Many thanks.

Comment: Just don't throw the error that you're currently throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your app is stopping is you're using `throw` when an error is returned by `save()`.

That results in an [`'uncaughtException'`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) event on the `process` object which if it has no listener will cause your process to exit.

Typically in Node.js you don't use `throw` unless the app should stop or the code is synchronous (IE `JSON.parse()`)

You should instead communicate that the error occurred back to the caller following the error first callback convention used throughout Node.js

```
newUser.save(function(err) {
  if(err)
    return done(err); // Let caller handle error

  return done(null, newUser);
});
```

To give a more End-to-End example assuming you're using Express to handle requests to the DB from an HTTP Request

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const createUser = function(myid, myname, done)
  User.findOne({id:myid}, function(err, user){
    if(err) 
      return done(err);
    if(user) 
      return done(null, user);

    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.name = myname;
    newUser.id = myid

    newUser.save(function(err){
      if(err) 
        return done(err)

      return done(null, newUser);
    });  
  }           
}); 

app.post('/users', function(req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.myid || !req.body.myname)
    return res.status(400).send('missing myid or myname from request body')

  createUser(req.body.myid, req.body.myname, (err, newUser) => {
    if(err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);  // Typically some error handling goes here

     return res.status(201).send(newUser);
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, () => { console.log('Listening' )});
```

Answer (score 1):

The server will stop when you throw and error to it.  In your code below you need to gracefully handle the error instead.

```
newUser.save(function(err){
                if(err) throw err; // handle gracefully
                return done(null, newUser);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the error instead of throwing it. Upon handling the error, you should send an appropriate HTTP Status/Message to the client (AngularJS app) where it then acts upon the possible server responses.